# Does Saturation velocity in semiconductors have a relation with the wavelength in which the peak in the absorption spectrum occurs?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, absorption

> Saturation velocity is the maximum velocity a charge carrier in a semiconductor, generally an electron, attains in the presence of very high electric fields.

([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_velocity))

I want to know if the absorption peak can be calculated with this parameter when a semiconductor like GaAs is under illumination.

Answer (score 1):

Well you seem to be mixing apples with oranges.

Absorption of a photon in GaAs  depends on the bandgap of the material (taking doping into effect) and the photon energy, and doesn't have much of anything to do with electric fields.

The effective collection of any carriers generated from the photon absorption may be influenced by the electric fields, but that is usually not an important effect.

GaAs used as a PV solar energy collector, is invariably operated in the forward Voltage mode, so there aren't any very high electric fields; and if you use it in reverse bias mode as a linear detector, then you don't want to use very high Voltages, which will increase the leakage.   If you use it in avalanche mode, then you can get a signal gain, at the cost of noise and linearity.  But my digression doesn't really answer your specific question which relates to the peak of the absorption spectrum.    Processes which create long wave tails that are normally absent, may change the spectrum, but that would have little effect on the wavelength of peak absorption which is not a tail "fringe" effect.

Comment: Yes, to be honest I'm a little confused. Would you please tell me how can I find the parameters affecting the absorption of semiconductor in theory

Comment: Well Dana, much as I would like to be able to give such instruction to new students of such things, there simply isn't enough hours in my day to help people research the available literature.   I get MY answers out of MY head; and it has forgotten more than it remembers.   One book that might help is "The Light Emitting Diode".  By Arpad Bergh and ?.Dean.   See I can't remember Dean's name; but I have the book if I need to know it.  The book relates to the early days of LEDs and has much basic stuff on photon absorption and emission in the III-V compounds such as GaAs and GaP in particular.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the full name and authors of the book for those who are interested:
Light-Emitting Diodes, by Arpad A. Bergh, Paul J. Dean

Comment: @GeorgeE.Smith -Actually, electric fields do affect they absorption spectrum of semiconductors, the lower the threshold below the bandgap. This is known as  Franz–Keldysh effect.

Comment: Well III-V semiconductors for LEDs or PV cells are virtually never intrinsic materials so the photon absorption energy is typically less than the bandgap anyhow.  To make a good PV cell, you first have to make a good LED; see Eli Yablonovitch at UC Berkeley.  You can stimulate photo-luminescence from GaAsP (60:40) with a 632.8 nm HeNe laser and get a 655 nm  PL spectrum peak with the laser line clearly impinged on the long wave tail. I guess in 57 years of working on LEDs I never needed to know of the Franz-Keldysh effect.  Bergh and Dean likely never did either.

Comment: This is actually a correction to my previous comment.  When stimulating photo-luminescence in 60/40 GaAsP with a HeNe 632.8 nm red laser, the sharp laser peak of course ends up on the SHORT wavelength tail , not the LONG wavelength tail.   The remarkable thing is that the emitted photo-luminescence peak seems to show no local disturbance near the laser peak; and I always wondered how the material could be emitting higher energy photons.  Evidently QM explains all that.

Comment: One other comment relating to the tails of absorption spectra.   To register a photon absorption in a photo-electric material, there has to be a photon capture that depends on the photon energy, and material properties, followed by carrier generation, normally a hole electron pair.  The internal quantum efficiency determines the probability of that occurrence.   To detect the event, the carriers have to be collected, and measured.   Some will vanish due to recombination.  High fields aid collection, creating the illusion of a higher internal quantum efficiency.

Comment: @Dana, for a reference book try J. Pankove "Optical processes in Semiconductors."  It's the "classic"